# Android NDK: OpenGL draw calls in thread outside of android_main

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, pthreads, android-ndk

I have a purely native Android NDK app. The main loop is in

```
 android_main
```

as provided by the android_native_app_glue.h.

I need to render something in a separate thread, so via android_main I tried:

```
 pthread_t thread1;
 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, renderstuff, NULL);

void *renderstuff( void *ptr )
{
  // some opnegl es draw calls
}
```

However this does not render anything. If I perform the same draw calls from within android_main (but without creating a new thread), it renders fine :S

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I ended up reworking things to ensure that only a single thread performs the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest, I saw your post, and here's my $0.02 (I have texturing in background threads working on Android using shared contexts):

`eglCreateContext` must be called from the thread which owns the context to share.  Following the call to `eglCreateContext`, your call to `eglMakeCurrent` (from within the newly spawned thread) should work.

Comment: If you make yourself comfortable with the editing tools, you can highlight code in your answer which often makes things easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `eglMakeCurrent()` in your new thread at all? You need to do so before any draw calls on the new thread.

Comment: hmm no I didn't, but I know that my new thread is being entered as I also have some log statements being printed out.

Comment: Yeah that's a requirement for multithreaded OpenGL rendering. If you don't want to deal with such things, initialize and draw on the new thread.

Comment: hmm unfortunately I tried to use eglMakeCurrent, but it returns EGL_FALSE! :s

Comment: Before I do so, I found that the error I'm getting is "EGL_BAD_ACCESS". I simply create a new EGLContext in the new thread using eglCreateContext, while reusing my EGLSurface and EGLDisplay. (Basically I need to render to the same window using two different threads).

Comment: So you want to do multithreaded rendering instead of rendering everything in another thread? When creating the EGLContexts for each thread, don't forget to pass in the EGLContext to share with and call `makeCurrent()` before any rendering calls.

Comment: thanks - though I still could not get it to work. I have decided to work around this by sticking to a single rendering thread. Appreciate the help!